# Purchased apps lost after Apple ID change

Tags: ipad, apple-id

I received an unsolicited email from Apple telling me that my Apple ID was changed.

Before the email, my Apple ID was, let's say, 'myself'; after it is 'myself@gmail.com'.
After this change I cannot update previously purchased apps on my iPad 2 (iOS 7.0.1).
And I cannot see my old purchases in the App Store.

I can still download new apps. And I can see these new apps in my purchases.

I already tried logging out and in again in the App Store.

Does anybody know of a solution to this problem?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but purchases are tied to an apple id and currently Apple does not provide a way to merge Apple ID's.   However since Apple changed your id without your permission then they may help you out.  Best thing to do is call Apple and ask why the Apple ID was changed.

This comes right from Apple's faq page (http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5622) about Apple ID's:

> Apple IDs cannot be merged. You should use your preferred Apple ID
>   from now on, but you can still access your purchased items such as
>   music, movies, or software using your other Apple IDs.